# Mystery material in bathroom ceiling in 1887 Victorian mansion of New England

Tags: ceiling

I'm not sure how to treat this ceiling. Board of Health says seal those holes. I also want to seal the whole ceiling from dropping crumbs, but first, what is that ceiling material?

[image]   [image]

[image]   [image]

Comment: It is cement plaster with peeling paint. Zooming in to the first picture you can see the old style diamond metal lath.

Comment: I'd agree with @Kyle who should make an answer out of that. Also, when zooming into that first picture, the orange line looks _very_ much like an _extension cord_, not #10 wire (it looks round, not oval). Extension cordage is _NOT_ allowed to be buried in the ceiling like that - it's a code violation. While you're up there, that should be fixed. It's possible that it's a 10/3 and that would be round, so double check on that one.

Comment: @FreeMan, it could be a run of 10/3, to an oven or water heater.

Comment: Yeah, @Jack, I thought about that after my initial comment, hence the edit. It should be double checked, just to be on the safe side. Simply reading the labeling on the jacket should be sufficient to identify it. If the OP isn't sure, a good, clear pic of the labeling [edit]ed into the post will be promptly identified by someone here.

Comment: Why is the Board of Health involved?  Is this not a private home?

Comment: Thanks all. It was built in an prosperous era by a silk barren family. It now houses low income residents. I'm thinking the wire is for an oven, but I will have to check it out when I'm there next. Thanks again! Please, anyone know how I can seal it in a low cost way? I could scrape and paint, or should I try another layer of cement plaster instead to do something more proper? I am wondering if the cement plaster would bond and stay up.

Comment: Is it not a bad possibility that the plaster contains asbestos?  And is not that crumbling extremely hazardous to release the asbestos fibers?  I don't think asbestos was used in 1800's, and was not used until early 1900's, but that plaster could have been redone sometime within the past 100 years and probably should be tested.

Comment: @user155408 Please [merge your accounts](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Note that posting responses as answers can result in an [automated lock](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) that can prevent others from assisting you.